# Any value of separating a MySQL query into $query and $result?

Tags: php, mysql

I always see MySQL queries structured like this, even with the simplest of queries:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id = '1'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Is there any value, time or otherwise in doing the above over a simple one line query such as?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id = '1'";
```

I've always used the former, as when I started using PHP I thought it best to simply copy everyone else, however now that I'm working on a fairly large (relative to my other work) application, I could cut out a significant amount of arbitrary coding if there's really no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, I like separating them because I can easily do `print $query;` when I'm trying to figure out why my query won't work. It's mostly a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 3):

With the first, it's easier to log the SQL in case something went wrong (and it's easier to spot typos, like a missing bracket).

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but could you please further explain "..it's easier to log the SQL instead something went wrong"?

Comment: Say you define a `log()` function. You can do `log($query)` instead of having to copy/paste the query into it (and remember to copy the changes every time you tweak). Basically the same benefit as my answer - easy reuse of the query for other things.

Comment: Pixelatron: what ceejayoz said, and also - typo, my bad, you saw it before I fixed it :-) (Karma's a bitch..)

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no difference at all except for one thing. If you put your query in seperate variable then you can reuse that. If any changes occur in query you just need to edit the query in variable

Answer (score 0):

You can always create a custom function that takes in a query and runs it, and pass additional optional arguments in case you want it to return the query, or log the query to track any issues etc.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any value, time or otherwise in doing the above over a simple one line query such as?

sure, as MSpreij said, you can examine your query in case of error.

I always see MySQL queries structured like this, even with the simplest of queries:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id = '1'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." ".$query);
```

this simple construct will save you a dozen whines in stackoverflow "what does it mean `mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result`"

notice the additional part. This is called *programming*.
It will print your query *automatically*, in case of error, along with mysql error message. Or log it into error log in a live server with appropriate settings.

Without writing `print $query;` manually.

However, both methods are ugly as hell.

## One should never use raw API functions at all.

It's ugly, unmaintainable, bloated and repetitive.

One should develop *a library*, a function to make a call more intelligent and less repetitive

```
$data = mydb_get_row("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id = 1");
```

having all the processing inside. with error handling, query logging, parameter checking and api functions calling.
yet as a **true** one-liner, not a silly one you were trying to achieve.

Comment: You know what, that's absolutely brilliant! I've got a million and one sets of four-five `mysql_x()` function calls, that are repeated over and over again and could be cut down significantly.